# How to find route for pedestrian

Tags: navigation, walking

I want to make long foot trip from Salzburg via Innsbruck to Milan and from there to Venice.

Is there a tool that allows me create routes for pedestrian? I'm looking for things like walking on sidewalks, avoiding rush roads etc.

Comment: Cant speak for the rest of the route but from Milan to Venice you will find quite a bit of roads without sidewalks to walk on and pretty heavy traffic

Comment: Openstreetmap.org often has more detailed information on walking and bike paths than google maps. However, their software for finding a route from A to B was pretty bad the last time I tried it.

Comment: @Karolina Ticha How was the trip? :) did you do it in the end? and what tool did you use for the planning?

Answer (score 6):

I often use [Bikemap.net](https://www.bikemap.net/), not only for bike trails, but also for hikes: has really good maps and also nice route planning functions; you can save your maps to be available offline, and then track them on your smartphone. Or you can print the detailed maps, frame by frame.

The Bikemap page took me to [Wandermap.net](http://www.wandermap.net/) which also seems to be useful, but I somehow got used to the first one.

Not sure if these cover what you mean by "walking on sideways", but if uncertain about pavements on a route, you may always double check satellite recordings on google maps too.

Answer (score 4):

**Have you tried [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/)?**

On the top-left corner there's a blue button to ask for directions:

[image: Ask for directions]

I [tried to enter your route](https://www.google.com.mx/maps/dir/Salzburg,+Austria/Innsbruck+Hbf,+Austria/Milan,+Metropolitan+City+of+Milan,+Italy/Venice,+Italy/@46.5738116,9.9989107,8z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m26!4m25!1m5!1m1!1s0x47769adda908d4b1:0xc1e183a1412af73d!2m2!1d13.05501!2d47.80949!1m5!1m1!1s0x479d695813109cdb:0x4a56cb35e59c9811!2m2!1d11.4005366!2d47.2634797!1m5!1m1!1s0x4786c1493f1275e7:0x3cffcd13c6740e8d!2m2!1d9.1859243!2d45.4654219!1m5!1m1!1s0x477eaa16cb134829:0x307098715907f10!2m2!1d12.4177003!2d45.4930475!3e2?hl=en) and it shows me a seemingly decent route.

Just be sure to indicate that you're walking (1), and add your source and destinations (2). You can use the *plus-sign* (3) to add more waypoints:

[image: Google Maps controls]

I understand that Google takes into account rush roads and stuff like that:
[image: Avoid rush roads]

On a final note, if you want to change the route, you can drag the white points elsewhere and it will calculate another route.

As [@Mark](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/3112/mark) pointed out, you should expect for it to have a few flaws (as will any solution not based on first-hand experience from previous hikers).
If you have time to plan, you *could* minimize this by using [street view](https://www.google.com.mx/maps/dir/Salzburg,+Austria/Innsbruck+Hbf,+Austria/Milan,+Metropolitan+City+of+Milan,+Italy/Venice,+Italy/@45.4559826,12.2946399,3a,75y,127.93h,71.16t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sT2UNRTYBNli_D09eXO7fTA!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo3.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3DT2UNRTYBNli_D09eXO7fTA%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D63.48679%26pitch%3D0!7i13312!8i6656!4m26!4m25!1m5!1m1!1s0x47769adda908d4b1:0xc1e183a1412af73d!2m2!1d13.05501!2d47.80949!1m5!1m1!1s0x479d695813109cdb:0x4a56cb35e59c9811!2m2!1d11.4005366!2d47.2634797!1m5!1m1!1s0x4786c1493f1275e7:0x3cffcd13c6740e8d!2m2!1d9.1859243!2d45.4654219!1m5!1m1!1s0x477eaa16cb134829:0x307098715907f10!2m2!1d12.4177003!2d45.4930475!3e2?hl=en) to see if there really is a sidewalk there.
Either way: be sure you're ready to improvise or even backtrack.

Comment: I wouldn't trust Google for walking routes.  I had it give me a route from my office to an auto mechanic, and what it offered involved walking down a quarter-mile of a street prominently marked "no pedestrians", then crossing six lanes of heavy traffic.

Comment: @Mark Yes thanks. We often forget that technology is not infallible and will only help us as much. I added a bit at the end.